# what does -cat tty: true mean in yaml configuration of kubernetes agent in Jenkinsfile?

Tags: kubernetes, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
spec:
  serviceAccountName: <service account name in kubernetes>
  containers:
  - name: spark-submit
    image: <image arn>
    command:
    - cat
    tty: true
  - name: kube-tools
    image: <image arn>
    command:
    - cat
    tty: true
```

this is the part of yaml configuration of kubernetes agent in Jenkinsfile, what does the **- cat  tty: true** means?
i suppose tty: true means activating the terminal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please note that these are two different settings.
With `tty: true` you enable a TTY which is required for execution of a shell.

The second is `cat` as argument for the container `command`. It means that the `cat` executable is run without further arguments.
If you run `cat` on a terminal yourself in this , you will notice that it does nothing, but blocks and waits for input. The reason is that the `cat` command ("concatenate" in short) reads input from a file or stdin and prints it. If there is nothing, it just waits. (See the manpage here as well: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cat.1.html )

That is often the sole idea: Start a container or Pod and keep it running. It will be terminated by other means.
You can think of it like `sleep (infinity)`.

Comment: can you explain information you gave on **cat** in layman terms

Comment: I updated the answer, does it make more sense to you now?